# Setstate Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Boa tarde.

Estou iniciando com flutter (vim do ReactNative), assistindo alguns cursos... e me surgiu a dúvida: O que realmente o setState controla?

No ReactNative ele olha tudo o que setamos no objeto "state" através do método setState(). Porém no flutter eu tenho esse trecho de código:

```
setState(() {
   bloc.calculate();
});
```

E ele atualiza na tela os dados que estão armazenados na instância da classe. Logo tudo que eu crio, new Bloc(), new Map... dentro da classe de state do meu component será "observado"?

Comment: Da uma lida aqui na [documentação](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) para ver se suas dúvidas são sanadas... Caso não, depois quando tiver um tempo deixo uma resposta mais explicativa. PS: Se tiver usando o padrão BLoC, não há necessidade de utilizar setState().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na documentção do [setState()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) podemos encontrar o seguinte:

> - Notify the framework that the internal state of this object has
>     changed.
> - Calling setState notifies the framework that the internal
>     state of this object has changed in a way that might impact the user
>     interface in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a
>     build for this State object.

Então podemos entender que o `setState()` ao ser chamado, vai redesenhar o seu Widget ou melhor, vai chamar seu método `build` novamente, mas não irá ficar "ouvindo" as mudanças... Caso ocorra alguma outra alteração no objeto, para ser redesenhado novamente, você precisa chamar o `setState()` mais uma vez.

**Exemplo**

No exemplo abaixo, ao chamar o `setState()`, você vai estar chamando novamente o `build`, assim os dados na tela serão redesenhados com os novos valores setados.

```
class Cliente{
  String nome = "";
  String sobrenome = "";
}

class CadastroCliente extends StatefulWidget {
  const CadastroCliente({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CadastroClienteState createState() => _CadastroClienteState();
}

class _CadastroClienteState extends State<CadastroCliente> {

  Cliente cliente = Cliente();
  String apelido = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget> [
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(cliente.nome),
            Text(cliente.sobrenome),
            Text(apelido),
            RaisedButton( /* Botão 1 */
              child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
              onPressed: (){
                setState((){
                  cliente.nome = "Matheus";
                });
                cliente.sobrenome = "Ribeiro";
                apelido = "Matt";
              }
            ),
          ]
        )
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

*~~ É apenas um exemplo para entendimento, pode haver alguns erros ao tentar rodar :D ~~*

Não sei dizer ao certo o porque, mas é aconselhável você setar os valores dentro do

```
setState((){ 
   cliente.nome = "Matheus";
   cliente.sobrenome = "Ribeiro";
   apelido = "Matt";
});
```

por ser um método síncrono, é bom fazer o que precisa dentro dele mesmo.

E sim, todos os objetos que estão na `_CadastroClienteState` serão testados para ver se possuem valores novos, no momento em que o `build` for chamado novamente.

**Observação**

Se você está utilizando o padrão BLoC, você não irá utilizar o `setState()`, de uma estudada sobre, pois é interessante você utilizar `StreamBuilder` dentro de um `StatelessWidget`.

Comment: Os valores tem que ser setados dentro do setState porque ele age como uma transaction. Caso dê errado, ele dá um rollback.
Obrigado pela explicação.